# Laptop only detects TV via HDMI when the TV is off

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, hdmi, tv

I have an Acer Aspire 5951G laptop with an NVIDIA GeForce GT 555M graphics card and 64-bit Windows 7.

I am pretty sure that none of the components (HDMI-cable, graphics card, TV) are malfunctioning. However, my laptop only detects the LG TV whenever the TV is turned off.

I have tried rebooting the computer while connected to the TV when the TV is on but no luck.

Comment: Have you tried updating the video driver?  Uninstalling the video driver and reinstalling it?  Running Windows Updates?  etc.

Comment: Yup, I did all the things you mentioned. But my computer still only detects the TV when it is off.

Answer (score 1):

I got it all worked out. Apparently the issue is from the TV. 
Because I am using the TV from a hotel, so the HDMI is actually deactivated by the hotel.

By simply unplugging the phone line at the back, I can switch to the HDMI channel I want.

Thanks for all the help